# Prove the following product using Gamma and Beta function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

This is the problem $3874$ of 5000 problems in mathematical analysis.
Prove that:
$
\prod_{m=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{m-1}e^{-{x^n}} \,dx= (\frac{1}{n})^{n-\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}.
$

I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{m-1}e^{-{x^n}}=\frac{1}{n}\Gamma \left( \frac{m}{n} \right)$, then, we have that, $\prod_{m=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{m-1}e^{-{x^n}} \,dx= (\frac{1}{n})^n \prod_{m=1}^{n} \Gamma \left( \frac{m}{n} \right)$. But i don't know how to get the terms $(\frac{1}{n})^{n-1/2}(2\pi)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: What you probably want to look at is the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) for the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(2z) = \frac{2^{2z-1}}{\sqrt \pi}\Gamma(z)  \Gamma\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

As it happens, for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$, it can be generalized to

$$\Gamma(nz) = (2\pi)^{(1-n)/2} n^{nz-1/2} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \Gamma \left( z + \frac k n \right)$$